# Python: Grab each word after certain character in string

Tags: python, string, split, slice, irc

I want to grab each word that has a + before it

If I input the string:

```
 word anotherword +aspecialword lameword +heythisone +test hello
```

I want it to return:

```
 aspecialword heythisone test
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try like this:

```
>>> my_str = "word anotherword +aspecialword lameword +heythisone +test hello"
>>> " ".join(x[1:] for x in my_str.split() if x.startswith("+"))
'aspecialword heythisone test'
```

> str.startswith(prefix[, start[, end]])
>
> Return True if string starts with the prefix, otherwise return False. prefix can also be a tuple of prefixes to look for. With optional start, test string beginning at that position. With optional end, stop comparing string at that position.

Answer (score 3):

Have a `split` combined with a list comp

```
>>> a = 'word anotherword +aspecialword lameword +heythisone +test hello'
>>> [i[1:] for i in a.split() if i[0] == '+']
['aspecialword', 'heythisone', 'test']
```

Comment: You don't really need to pass `' '` to split, only if you wanted to preseve the spacing if you were rejoining etc..

Comment: @PadraicCunningham Disadvantages of learning *"other"* languages

Comment: Are you cheating on python? ;)

Answer (score 1):

You could use a regular expression.

```
>>> import re
>>> re.findall(r'(?<=\+)\S+', "word anotherword +aspecialword lameword +heythisone +test hello")
['aspecialword', 'heythisone', 'test']
```

`r'(?<=\+)\S+'` matches any sequence of non-space characters that are preceded by a plus sign.

Comment: You could also use a grenade to go fishing ;)

Comment: @PadraicCunningham i am laughing a loud on this comment haaaaaaa

Comment: @PadraicCunningham Wow really? I assumed there would be laws against it. I will get right on that!

Comment: @khelwood, no doubt you can do it  somewhere in the world,  maybe a few regex patterns for a bit of  google parsing and will be able to findall your way there.